# How to 'checksum' an array of noisy floating point numbers?

Tags: testing, encoding, floating-point, error-correction

What is a quick and easy way to 'checksum' an array of floating point numbers, while allowing for a specified small amount of inaccuracy?

e.g. I have two algorithms which should (in theory, with infinite precision) output the same array. But they work differently, and so floating point errors will accumulate differently, though the array lengths should be exactly the same. I'd like a quick and easy way to test if the arrays seem to be the same. I could of course compare the numbers pairwise, and report the maximum error; but one algorithm is in C++ and the other is in Mathematica and I don't want the bother of writing out the numbers to a file or pasting them from one system to another. That's why I want a simple checksum.

I could simply add up all the numbers in the array. If the array length is N, and I can tolerate an error of 0.0001 in each number, then I would check if `abs(sum1-sum2)<0.0001*N`. But this simplistic 'checksum' is not robust, e.g. to an error of +10 in one entry and -10 in another. (And anyway, probability theory says that the error probably grows like sqrt(N), not like N.) Of course, any checksum is a low-dimensional summary of a chunk of data so it will miss *some* errors, if not most... but simple checksums are nonetheless useful for finding non-malicious bug-type errors.

Or I could create a two-dimensional checksum, `[sum(x[n]), sum(abs(x[n]))]`. But is the best I can do, i.e. is there a different function I might use that would be "more orthogonal" to the `sum(x[n])`? And if I used some arbitrary functions, e.g. `[sum(f1(x[n])), sum(f2(x[n]))]`, then how should my 'raw error tolerance' translate into 'checksum error tolerance'?

I'm programming in C++, but I'm happy to see answers in any language.

Comment: This is not the purpose of a checksum.  A checksum is for determining bit-exactness, not for tolerance testing.

Comment: Interesting question.  Have you thought of Fourier-transforming the data, possibly in conjunction with low-pass filtering?

Comment: @Oli: My question makes it clear what I'm looking for, and I'm not aware of a better word for what I want. If you know a better word, let me know and I'll use it instead. For now, I've put the word checksum in quotation marks.

Comment: I believe what you seek is impossible, since the dimension of the spaces is different.  (You "lose information" when you map an n-dimensional space to a smaller-dimensional space.)  Even a checksum on a set of integers only guarantees different checksums => different sets, not vice-versa.  tlb's suggestion is probably about as good as you will get in practice.

Comment: I know that checksums lose information. I've edited the question to make that clearer. Nonetheless, checksums are useful as a first-cut check against silly errors, and I want something with the same properties.

Comment: a sum is also dominated by errors in the largest value.  do you have *any* expectations about the result that could help.  for example, if all are the same magnitude.

Comment: @andrew: The array length is around 500. The numbers are all in the range [0,240]. I anticipate (and can tolerate) fixed-precision errors of 0.0001. I anticipate that the numbers will be multimodal, with a peak around 0, and three or four other peaks, each of std.dev around 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent a while looking for a deterministic answer, and been unable to find one. If there is a good answer, it's likely to require heavy-duty mathematical skills (functional analysis).

I'm pretty sure there is no solution based on "discretize in some cunning way, then apply a discrete checksum", e.g. "discretize into strings of 0/1/?, where ? means wildcard". Any discretization will have the property that two floating-point numbers very close to each other can end up with different discrete codes, and then the discrete checksum won't tell us what we want to know.

However, a very simple randomized scheme should work fine. Generate a pseudorandom string S from the alphabet {+1,-1}, and compute csx=sum(X_i*S_i) and csy=sum(Y_i*S_i), where X and Y are my original arrays of floating point numbers. If we model the errors as independent Normal random variables with mean 0, then it's easy to compute the distribution of csx-csy. We could do this for several strings S, and then do a hypothesis test that the mean error is 0. The number of strings S needed for the test is fixed, it doesn't grow linearly in the size of the arrays, so it satisfies my need for a "low-dimensional summary". This method also gives an estimate of the standard deviation of the error, which may be handy.

Answer (score 3):

i have a feeling that what you want may be possible via something like [gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).  if you could translate your values into gray codes and use some kind of checksum that was able to correct n bits you could detect whether or not the two arrays were the same except for n-1 bits of error, right?  (each bit of error means a number is "off by one", where the mapping would be such that this was a variation in the least significant digit).

but the exact details are beyond me - particularly for floating point values.

i don't know if it helps, but what gray codes solve is the problem of pathological rounding.  rounding sounds like it will solve the problem - a naive solution might round and then checksum.  but simple rounding always has pathological cases - for example, if we use floor, then 0.9999999 and 1 are distinct.  a gray code approach seems to address that, since neighbouring values are always single bit away, so a bit-based checksum will accurately reflect "distance".

[update:] more exactly, what you want is a checksum that gives an estimate of the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between your gray-encoded sequences (and the gray encoded part is easy if you just care about 0.0001 since you can multiple everything by 10000 and use integers).

and it seems like such checksums [do exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction): *Any error-correcting code can be used for error detection. A code with minimum Hamming distance, d, can detect up to d − 1 errors in a code word. Using minimum-distance-based error-correcting codes for error detection can be suitable if a strict limit on the minimum number of errors to be detected is desired.*

so, just in case it's not clear:

- multiple by minimum error to get integers
- convert to gray code equivalent
- use an error detecting code with a minimum hamming distance larger than the error you can tolerate.

but i am still not sure that's right.  you still get the pathological rounding in the conversion from float to integer.  so it seems like you need a minimum hamming distance that is 1 + len(data) (worst case, with a rounding error on each value).  is that feasible?  probably not for large arrays.

maybe ask again with better tags/description now that a general direction is possible?  or just add tags now?  we need someone who does this for a living.  [i added a couple of tags]

Comment: This is a very helpful suggestion. You've narrowed it down to a question about corner cases in rounding floats to integers, which is a much tighter question than the one I asked, and probably soluble. I'll think about it and see if I can turn it into an algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure this would distinguish between lots of off-by-one errors and one massive error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

// PARAMETERS
const size_t no_freqs = 3;
const double freqs[no_freqs] = {0.05, 0.16, 0.39}; // (for example)

int main() {
    std::complex<double> spectral_amplitude[no_freqs];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < no_freqs; ++i) spectral_amplitude[i] = 0.0;
    size_t n_data = 0;
    {
        std::complex<double> datum;
        while (std::cin >> datum) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < no_freqs; ++i) {
                spectral_amplitude[i] += datum * std::exp(
                    std::complex<double>(0.0, 1.0) * freqs[i] * double(n_data)
                );
            }
            ++n_data;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Fuzzy checksum:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < no_freqs; ++i) {
        std::cout << real(spectral_amplitude[i]) << "\n";
        std::cout << imag(spectral_amplitude[i]) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It returns just a few, arbitrary points of a Fourier transform of the entire data set.  These make a fuzzy checksum, so to speak.

Comment: Hmmm.  Do you have any reason to believe that this should have the properties that the OP desires, given that the FT is simply a linear transform of the input?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But why would a Fourier transform be any better than any other arbitrary function? I don't understand how my error tolerance in the raw numbers translates into an error tolerance in the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Right.  It depends on what you want, but the Fourier transform is pretty hard to fool if you choose arbitrary frequencies from it.  Since you expect some error, you can analyze Fourier straightforwardly, representing the error mathematically as a random variable with desired statistical properties -- or just as some fixed error function, if you don't want to mess with the stochastic mathematics.  Depending on your need, maybe you could eschew the analysis altogether, just trying Fourier and seeing if it doesn't do what you want.  You're better placed to judge your need than I.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  If linearity is an issue, one could apply a nonlinear function like std::arctan2(std::log(x), 1.0) to each data point before transforming the data.  One could also reorder the data points in some predetermined way.

Comment: +1.  There is no perfect solution in general.  But a big change to any single component should cause a noticeable change in ALL of the Fourier amplitudes (FFT of delta function = constant), so this looks like a reasonable suggestion to me.

Comment: @thb. I know how to analyse the error from simple checksums like sum(x[n]). I don't know how to analyse it for the Fourier transform, and I certainly don't know how to for arctan2(log(x),1). If I'm going to do invent arbitrary functions, what's the point in the Fourier transform -- why not just stick to sum?

Comment: @DamonJW:  Maybe you should just stick to sum.  On the other hand, for a frequency of 0.0, the Fourier transform *is* the sum.  At other frequencies, the Fourier transform is what you might call a "sum remix."  It's another way of looking at the sum -- actually, several other ways, one at each frequency.  But I'll not try to sell you on Fourier!  It was just an idea.  I don't think that I can carry my defense of it much further that I already have.  If it doesn't suit, fair enough.  Let us know when you do decide what to use, though.  I'll be interested.

Answer (score 1):

How about computing a standard integer checksum on the data obtained by zeroing the least significant digits of the data, the ones that you don't care about?